# Displaying image from different disk

Tags: php, html

Hi i want to show images from different disk.
Here is my code.
is it possible to do that ?

```
      $a = "D:/img/1.jpg";
      <img src="<?php echo $a; ?>"  alt="...">
```

Im using this on my localhost.This is not for the web.

i add screenshot here.
when i come above the img it shows the link. but not show img. and i use lightbox.
but without lightbox its not show again.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqSJ4.jpg)

Comment: `D:` isn't going to be web accessible.

Comment: i will use it on local

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865730/url-to-file-in-non-web-accessible-directory-readfile-fopen

Comment: @ÖzgürŞana ya, you better change it to your local. so the image can be accessible through website too.

Comment: @chris85 i checked but didnt get it.

Comment: Maybe this one is more direct, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-image-to-base64-encoding You need to get the bytes to PHP then throw it to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you provided/attached is only doable if you load the html file directly to your browser. It is not possible if you load it via localhost. In your case, you will have to do something like this:

```
<?php
$image = file_get_contents('D:/img/1.jpg');
$image_codes = base64_encode($image);
?>
<image src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf-8;base64,<?php echo $image_codes; ?>" />
```

Reference: [How to retrieve and show images from another drive using src attribute in <img> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855443/how-to-retrieve-and-show-images-from-another-drive-using-src-attribute-in-img)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suppose to use such URLs with protocol: `$a = 'file:///D:/img/1.jpg';`

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: Can you add html code that is produced by your server? Because plain html works fine for me.

Comment: <a  class="img-responsive img-radio" href="D:/a/1.jpg" id="1" data-lightbox="1.jpg" >

no errors. server create this code

and i added ss. can u check it pls

Comment: oh sorry. this was lightbox code :)

here is img tag 
<img src="D:/a/1.jpg" class="asd" alt="..."> 

no errors there but not showing